# FreeBSD jail with IPFW with loopback - unable to connect loopback interface

Tags: freebsd, nat, ipfw

I am trying to configure a one IP jail with loopback interface, but I am unsure how to configure the IPFW rules to allow traffic to pass between the jail and the network card on the server.

I have followed http://blog.burghardt.pl/2009/01/multiple-freebsd-jails-sharing-one-ip-address/ and https://forums.freebsd.org/viewtopic.php?&t=30063

but without success, here is what i have in my `ipfw.rules`

```
# vim /usr/local/etc/ipfw.rules

ext_if="igb0"
jail_if="lo666"
IP_PUB="192.168.0.2"
IP_JAIL_WWW="10.6.6.6"
NET_JAIL="10.6.6.0/24"

IPF="ipfw -q add"
ipfw -q -f flush
#loopback
$IPF 10 allow all from any to any via lo0
$IPF 20 deny all from any to 127.0.0.0/8
$IPF 30 deny all from 127.0.0.0/8 to any
$IPF 40 deny tcp from any to any frag
# statefull
$IPF 50 check-state
$IPF 60 allow tcp from any to any established
$IPF 70 allow all from any to any out keep-state
$IPF 80 allow icmp from any to any
# open port ftp (20,21), ssh (22), mail (25)
# ssh (22), , dns (53) etc
$IPF 120 allow tcp from any to any 21 out
$IPF 130 allow tcp from any to any 22 in
$IPF 140 allow tcp from any to any 22 out
$IPF 150 allow tcp from any to any 25 in
$IPF 160 allow tcp from any to any 25 out
$IPF 170 allow udp from any to any 53 in
$IPF 175 allow tcp from any to any 53 in
$IPF 180 allow udp from any to any 53 out
$IPF 185 allow tcp from any to any 53 out

# HTTP
$IPF 300 skipto 63000 tcp from any to me http,https setup keep-state
$IPF 300 skipto 63000 tcp from any to me http,https setup keep-state
# deny and log everything
$IPF 500 deny log all from any to any
# NAT
$IPF 63000 divert natd ip from any to any via $jail_if out
$IPF 63000 divert natd ip from any to any via $jail_if in
```

but when i create a jail as:

```
# ezjail-admin create -f continental -c zfs node 10.6.6.7
/usr/jails/node/.
/usr/jails/node/./etc
/usr/jails/node/./etc/resolv.conf
/usr/jails/node/./etc/ezjail.flavour.continental
/usr/jails/node/./etc/rc.d
/usr/jails/node/./etc/rc.conf
4 blocks
find: /usr/jails/node/pkg/: No such file or directory
Warning: IP 10.6.6.7 not configured on a local interface.
Warning: Some services already seem to be listening on all IP, (including 10.6.6.7)
  This may cause some confusion, here they are:
root     syslogd    1203  6  udp6   *:514                 *:*
root     syslogd    1203  7  udp4   *:514                 *:*
```

i get these warning and then when i go into the jail environment, i am unable to install any ports.

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The guides you linked to both use the pf firewall instead of ipfw in their examples so it might be easier to troubleshoot if you were to also use pf. I myself am only familiar with configuring pf but I can suggest a few things that you might try.

1. Make sure that the external and loopback interfaces you are using are actually active by using the `ifconfig` command.
2. In your `/etc/rc.conf` make sure that the following lines exist:

> cloned_interfaces="lo666"
>
> ifconfig_lo666_alias0="inet 10.6.6.6 netmask 255.255.255.255"
>
> gateway_enable="YES"

Should you decide to use pf instead of ipfw I can try to be of further assistance.

Comment: this is the rc.conf i have https://gist.github.com/nkhine/fb8b2d2e67cab280ef5c

should i use PF instead of IPFW, I am on FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE-p3 (IPFWKERNEL) #1: Tue May 20 08:47:12 UTC 2014

the kernel was rebuilt as per http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-freebsd-ipfw-firewall/ guide

thanks